# Python - can I programmatically decorate class methods from a class instance?

Tags: python, decorator, class-method

I have an object hierarchy in which almost all of the methods are class methods.  It looks like the following:

```
class ParentObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def smile_warmly(cls, the_method):
        def wrapper(kls, *args, **kwargs):
            print "-smile_warmly - "+kls.__name__
            the_method(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @classmethod
    def greetings(cls):
        print "greetings"

class SonObject(ParentObject):
    @classmethod
    def hello_son(cls):
        print "hello son"

    @classmethod
    def goodbye(cls):
        print "goodbye son"

class DaughterObject(ParentObject):
    @classmethod
    def hello_daughter(cls):
        print "hello daughter"

    @classmethod
    def goodbye(cls):
        print "goodbye daughter"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    son = SonObject()
    son.greetings()
    son.hello_son()
    son.goodbye()
    daughter = DaughterObject()
    daughter.greetings()
    daughter.hello_daughter()
    daughter.goodbye()
```

The code as given outputs the following:

```
greetings
hello son
goodbye son
greetings
hello daughter
goodbye daughter
```

I would like the code to output the following:

```
-smile_warmly - SonObject
greetings
-smile_warmly - SonObject
hello son
-smile_warmly - SonObject
goodbye son
-smile_warmly - DaughterObject
greetings
-smile_warmly - DaughterObject
hello daughter
-smile_warmly - DaughterObject
goodbye daughter
```

But I don't want to add the line `@smile_warmly` before each method (and when I try to do that in the code above, I get error message `TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable`).  Rather, I would like the decoration of each method to take place programmatically in the `__init__()` method.

Is it possible to programmatically decorate methods in Python?

**EDIT**: Found something that seems to work -- see my answer below.  Thanks to BrenBarn.

Comment: Is the concept of metaclasses familiar to you?

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python  Maybe if you are set on using decorators this guy too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators

Comment: I've heard of them, but that's about it.  So no.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

All a decorator does is return a new function.  This:

```
@deco
def foo():
    # blah
```

is the same as this:

```
def foo():
    # blah
foo = deco(foo)
```

You can do the same thing whenever you like, without the `@` syntax, just by replacing functions with whatever you like.  So in `__init__` or wherever else, you could loop through all the methods and for each one replace it with `smilewarmly(meth)`.

However, instead of doing it in `__init__`, it would make more sense to do it when the class is created.  You could do this with a metaclass, or more simply with a class decorator:

```
def smileDeco(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kw):
        print ":-)"
        func(*args, **kw)
    return classmethod(wrapped)

def makeSmiley(cls):
    for attr, val in cls.__dict__.iteritems():
        if callable(val) and not attr.startswith("__"):
            setattr(cls, attr, smileDeco(val))
    return cls

@makeSmiley
class Foo(object):
    def sayStuff(self):
        print "Blah blah"

>>> Foo().sayStuff()
:-)
Blah blah
```

In this example I put the classmethod decoration inside my `smileDeco` decorator.  You could also put it in `makeSmiley` so that `makeSmiley` returned `smileDeco(classmethod(val))`.  (Which way you want to do it depends on how closely linked the smile-decorator is to the things being classmethods.)  This means you don't have to use `@classmethod` inside the class.

Also, of course, in the loop in `makeSmiley` you can include whatever logic you like to decide (for instance, based on the method's name) whether to wrap it with the smile behavior or not.

Note that you'd have to be a little more careful if you really want to manually use `@classmethod` inside the class, because classmethods as accessed via the class `__dict__` aren't callable.  So you'd have to specifically check whether the object is a classmethod object, instead of just checking whether it's callable.

Comment: This looks very helpful.  I'm trying to get it to work right now and will provide an update here if I can pull it off.

Comment: If I have dozens of classes that subclass my parent class, then I have to remember to decorate each class.  I'd prefer to just have the logic that adjusts the methods happen automatically in the `__init__()` method.  My child classes will not override __init__(), so the `__init__()` defined in the parent class will always be called when a child class is constructed.  If I could place similar logic there, then I'd have the functionality I desire.  So that's what I'm working on.

Comment: @JonCrowell: You can do that, but `__init__` is called for every *instance*, not every class, so it doesn't seem like what you want.  If you want the behavior to be fully automatic you'll have to use a metaclass.  You can read up on metaclasses [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python).

Comment: I have a class hierarchy in which I would like all methods to be class methods.  I almost have what I want, thanks to your pointers.  See my edit to my original question.  I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: See my answer below, which produces the output I desire.

Answer (score 1):

This solution produces the output I desire:

```
class ParentObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._adjust_methods(self.__class__)

    def _adjust_methods(self, cls):
        for attr, val in cls.__dict__.iteritems():
            if callable(val) and not attr.startswith("_"):
                setattr(cls, attr, self._smile_warmly(val))
        bases = cls.__bases__
        for base in bases:
            self._adjust_methods(base)

    def _smile_warmly(self, the_method):
        def _wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print "-smile_warmly - " +self.__name__
            the_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        cmethod_wrapped = classmethod(_wrapped)
        # cmethod_wrapped.adjusted = True
        return cmethod_wrapped

    def greetings(self):
        print "greetings"

class SonObject(ParentObject):
    def hello_son(self):
        print "hello son"

    def goodbye(self):
        print "goodbye son"

class DaughterObject(ParentObject):
    def hello_daughter(self):
        print "hello daughter"

    def goodbye(self):
        print "goodbye daughter"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    son = SonObject()
    son.greetings()
    son.hello_son()
    son.goodbye()
    daughter = DaughterObject()
    daughter.greetings()
    daughter.hello_daughter()
    daughter.goodbye()
```

The output is:

```
-smile_warmly - SonObject
greetings
-smile_warmly - SonObject
hello son
-smile_warmly - SonObject
goodbye son
-smile_warmly - DaughterObject
greetings
-smile_warmly - DaughterObject
hello daughter
-smile_warmly - DaughterObject
goodbye daughter
```

Comment: This will cause problems if you instantiate a class more than once, since it will then wrap the already-wrapped methods again.  At the least, you should set a flag on each class as you wrap it, to mark it as already wrapped.  Then you could check the flag at the beginning and skip the wrapping if the class is already wrapped.

Comment: Hmm - I think I might have screwed up.  My toy example given here gives the output I want, but my real code, which is more complicated, is giving me a bewildering `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` message and crashing.

Comment: You might want to post a new question with that issue.

Comment: Yes -- even now I'm creating a nice example to isolate the issue.  :)